How to change a PCH'ed external library into a header unit?
I read the following exciting idea:

Header units are the recommended alternative to precompiled header
files (PCH). Header units are easier to set up and use, are
significantly smaller on disk, provide similar performance benefits,
and are more flexible than a shared PCH.

So I thought I'd try to replace most of my old PCH usage with header units. ("most of" because I still need a PCH for when the header in question requires macro #defines for me to customize it).
My original precompiled.h file was:
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

So I removed the glm line and created a new glm.ixx file with the following contents:
#include "precompiled.h"
export module glm;

import <glm/glm.hpp>;

But then I got this build error for glm.hpp:

unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you
forget to add '#include "precompiled.h"' to your source?

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

This  works  for me.
#include "precompiled.h"
export module glm;

#include <glm/glm.hpp> 

After testing, even without  pch/Yu,  import <glm/glm.hpp>; cannot work like pch.h. But #include <glm/glm.hpp>  works.
glm.ixx:
export module glm;

import <glm/glm.hpp>;

cpp:
import glm;
//foo() that call method in  glm.hpp

foo() cannot find the declaration.
Edit:
.h
#pragma once

extern "C"  void foo();
extern "C"  class FooClass {
public:

    FooClass() ;
};

cpp
#include"pch.h"
#include"Foo.h"

extern "C"   void foo() {}


Thanks, I tried your solution but it doesn't work for me. Please see https://gist.github.com/logixoul/037442ee84590c705e951535a8853933

I was able to reproduce your problem. Due to my testing in a DLL,  I found that the C-style function can  solve the error. extern "C"  void foo().  In addition, foo() needs to be split into h and cpp files. Check my edit.

Ok, extern "C" works (though I'm not sure why), but if I add class FooClass { }; to foo.h, I'm unable to use that class in init.ixx (i.e. create a local variable via FooClass fc;). I get "FooClass: undeclared identifier"

It is  weird. extern "C"  class FooClass works.  Also, you could report an issue to Developer Community and post link here.
